# Rails: MIME type issues with .m4v files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types

In my Rails app I'm trying to get the MIME type of a file like so:

```
MIME::Types.type_for("example.m4v").to_s
```

But it's not recognizing it.

I tried adding the following to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` (and restarted the server) without any luck:

`Mime::Type.register "video/mp4", :m4v`

Comment: What does `it's not recognizing it` means?

Comment: Meaning nothing is returned when I do `type_for` as in my example above. Other extensions (.mov, .mp3, etc) return the type fine.

Comment: Have your sure that mime-type is send by your browser ? Because if it's not send by your browser, you can't use it in your Rails APP

Comment: My initial example works fine for pretty much any other extension. Again, if I change my example file name above to "example.mov" then that `type_for` returns `video/quicktime`...I just need to add a custom MIME type but can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the following lines to your `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file:

```
# register MIME type with Rails 
Mime::Type.register "video/mp4", :m4v

# register MIME type with MIME::Type gem 
MIME::Types.add(MIME::Type.from_array("video/mp4", %(m4v)))
```

Now in the console you can test the results

```
MIME::Types.type_for("abc.m4v").to_s
#=> "video/mp4"
```

Comment: One problem...I'm now getting this when I start my server: `Type video/mp4 already registered as a variant of video/mp4`

Comment: @Shpigford - did you ever figure out how to suppress that message?

Answer (score 0):

So I think there is Mime::Type and MIME::Types which are completely separate from each other.  Notice that it is "Mime" vs "MIME".

For example,

```
MIME::Types.type_for("foo.json")
```

returns

```
 [#<MIME::Type:0x1038b3108 @system=nil, @encoding="8bit", @simplified="application/json", @sub_type="json", @registered=true, @url=["IANA", "RFC4627"], @docs=nil, @obsolete=nil, @extensions=["json"], @raw_sub_type="json", @media_type="application", @raw_media_type="application", @content_type="application/json">]
```

Yet,

```
Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension("json")
```

returns

```
#<Mime::Type:0x1051c4d40 @symbol=:json, @string="text/x-json", @synonyms=[]>
```

So it looks like if you want to add a type so that it is returned when using type_for you can use the following:

```
>> t = MIME::Type.from_array('video/mp4', %w(m4v))
=> #<MIME::Type:0x1055de3b8 @system=nil, @encoding="base64", @simplified="video/mp4", @sub_type="mp4", @registered=true, @url=nil, @docs=nil, @obsolete=nil, @extensions=["m4v"], @raw_sub_type="mp4", @media_type="video", @raw_media_type="video", @content_type="video/mp4">
>> MIME::Types.add(t)
Type video/mp4 already registered as a variant of video/mp4.
=> [#<MIME::Type:0x1055de3b8 @system=nil, @encoding="base64", @simplified="video/mp4", @sub_type="mp4", @registered=true, @url=nil, @docs=nil, @obsolete=nil, @extensions=["m4v"], @raw_sub_type="mp4", @media_type="video", @raw_media_type="video", @content_type="video/mp4">]
>> MIME::Types.type_for("example.m4v")
=> [#<MIME::Type:0x1055de3b8 @system=nil, @encoding="base64", @simplified="video/mp4", @sub_type="mp4", @registered=true, @url=nil, @docs=nil, @obsolete=nil, @extensions=["m4v"], @raw_sub_type="mp4", @media_type="video", @raw_media_type="video", @content_type="video/mp4">]
>>
```

The warning when add is called is a little concerning so you should probably figure out how to append your extension to the "video/mp4" type. For more information check out the documentation for [MIME::Types](http://mime-types.rubyforge.org/classes/MIME/Types.html#M000005) and [MIME::Type](http://mime-types.rubyforge.org/classes/MIME/Type.html#M000005).

Comment: But the question here is how can I add a custom MIME type so the .m4v extension is recognized (as per my original example).

Comment: I updated my answer to include some code on how to add a custom MIME type. I'm not an expert in this area but hopefully this helps.