# HTML 5 video (ogv) and MIME types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video, mime-types

I can't figure out the following problem:

I use HTML 5 video on my web site. For crossbrowser support, I keep video in "mov" and "ogv" formats, so that Firefox can play it.

In ./config/initializers/mime_types.rb I have the following code:

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.merge!({
  ".ogg"     => "application/ogg",
  ".ogx"     => "application/ogg",
  ".ogv"     => "video/ogg",
  ".oga"     => "audio/ogg",
  ".mp4"     => "video/mp4",
  ".m4v"     => "video/mp4",
  ".mp3"     => "audio/mpeg",
  ".m4a"     => "audio/mpeg"
})
```

It works on my local machine, but won't on a production server.

I've tried many ways to make this work:

[Rails: MIME type issues with .m4v files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414474/rails-mime-type-issues-with-m4v-files)

[Setting Mime Type for .ogv files in Rails Development Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667430/setting-mime-type-for-ogv-files-in-rails-development-environment)

[Make OGG Video work with Rails](http://9elements.com/io/?p=306)

None of these helped me, and I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

On the production server or machine, if you are using a web server such as Nginx or Apache you need to declare those mime types within the respective config files for the server to rexognise it. Has this been done?

Comment: Hi. Yes, i've put .htaccess file with "AddType video/ogg .ogv" string, as pointed here: http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/tutorial-serving-html5-video-cross-browser-including-ipad/, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I observed a strange behavior where some of the ogv files gave a application/ogg mime type rather than video/ogg. Please check the mime type of the file you are uploading very carefully.