# Rails and HTML5 Video MimeTypes Unsupported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video, mime

I am working on a simple Rails app where I would like to play a video that is uploaded to the application. The video I am uploading is a h264/MP4 video, I have verified the codec. It's uploaded fine and I can watch the video in the browser if I go to the URL.

However, when trying to use HTML5 to display the video, on the page I get

`Video format or MIME type is not supported`

In my `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file I have tried the following...

```
Mime::Type.register "video/mp4", :mp4
MIME::Types.add(MIME::Type.from_array("video/mp4", %(mp4)))
```

Taken from this question: [Rails: MIME type issues with .m4v files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414474/rails-mime-type-issues-with-m4v-files)

And I have also tried...

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.merge!({
  ".ogg"     => "application/ogg",
  ".ogx"     => "application/ogg",
  ".ogv"     => "video/ogg",
  ".oga"     => "audio/ogg",
  ".mp4"     => "video/mp4",
  ".m4v"     => "video/mp4",
  ".mp3"     => "audio/mpeg",
  ".m4a"     => "audio/mpeg"
})
```

I remembered to restart my server after trying those different MIME initializers.

But neither seems to work. Any ideas?

EDIT: Also I should note when I run

`curl -I http://localhost:3000/videos/SAMPLE.mp4 | grep Content-Type`

I get back "Content-Type: video/mp4".

EDIT 2: Answer posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out everything I posted code-wise is fine. It was just a browser compatibility issue (MP4 on Firefox)...well, hopefully someone will find my misfortune useful!